# Mixed C and C++ project in TravisCI

Tags: c++, c, travis-ci

I have a project that uses a mix of C and C++ code, but currently you can only specify one `language` in the `.travis.yml` file.

In this case, should I use `language: c` or `language: cpp` or something else?

Comment: Can your C code be compiled in C++ mode?

Comment: @tadman - you mean can the `.c` files be compiled by invoking a C++ compiler like `g++` on them? No, they definitely use C-only features like VLAs and the designated initializer or whatever that thing is called.

Comment: Is there any way to fix that so you can use one compiler to handle them all? Could you make the `.c` code a dependent project and test the C++ against a pre-compiled library?

Comment: @tadman - sure, but that would be a big project re-organization and add a lot of complexity to the CI setup. I'm assuming there is some better solution, but if there isn't I guess I would just abandon my CI attempt for now.

Comment: A build server that only accepts a project with files written in _one_ language? That sounds useless for anything but hobby programming. Yet, huge names are using it. I wonder how they got around this restriction - maybe by breaking their projects up a bit into, like, moduley type things.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit - yup, that could be good in many cases for large multi-language projects. In this case I'm looking for a solution that doens't involve breaking up this project into modules. C and C++ are somewhat special here too since they can be naturally combined into the same binary at link time, and a single module could validly be composed of files from both languages (that's the case in my project).

Comment: Since Travis CI just uses a `Makefile` can't you get that to do the work of compiling things properly? The `language` hint is usually a key as to what build method to use, where `c` and `cpp` are probably both based on the usual `./configure && make && make test` approach.

Comment: @tadman - yeah, I gradually came the conclusion that the `cpp` tag is still set up to handle C compilation in the same way as the `c` tag (the reverse is not true), so that's probably the tag to use here (added an answer).

Answer (score 1):

When mixing C and C++ code, you can in practice just use the `cpp` language key. This still installs the C compilers; indeed, the supported C and C++ compilers are gcc/g++ and clang[++] which share a common implementation.

The `cpp` key still sets up the `CC` environment variable for C in addition to the `CXX` one for C++, and in [all other respects](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/languages/cpp/) appears to offer a superset functionality compared to what the `c` key uses.

The default `script` is `./configure && make && make test` for both languages, so even that is common.